# Setting up elementary os on macbook pro mid 2012

Tags: release-freya, settings, keyboard-shortcuts, hardware, macbook

There are some differences between a normal pc and a mac. This are the ones that obstruct me to make elementary os my main os. I know there are just details, but elementary is about details ;)

1) The headphone jack has a red light. How can i turn it off?

2) Is there a way to set the keyboard backlight to turn off after a some amount of time?

3) How can i switch the copy/paste keyboard shortcut to be cmd-c and cmd-p to have an experience more similar between os?

pd: sorry my bad english :$

Comment: You are asking several questions at once. For clarity, please ask one by one, divide your question into three separate questions.